# Remove date from DatePickerCell in gwt

Tags: gwt, gwt-mvp, gwt-celltable

I have implemented a CellTable in gwt, which has a column of type **DatePickerCell**, which opens a datepicker on click of the cell. I would like to implement something like DateBox, which has a textbox, on click of which a date picker will be opened and date can be removed from textbox, which does not happen in the case of DatePickerCell. I have tried to extend the DatePickerCell to use DateBox instead of DatePicker.

```
interface Template extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
    @Template("<input type=\"text\" value=\"{0}\" tabindex=\"-1\" style=\"width: 85px;\"></input>")
    SafeHtml div(String value);
}
```

Please help in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "a date picker will be opened and date can be removed from textbox" What do you mean by this

Comment: If data is celltable is populated with values...like start date and end date...if i want to remove the end date from the column...and save it in the database...how will the removing part from the gwt cell table column be??

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to create your own `DateBoxCell` by coping the class `DatePickerCell` and change the `DatePicker` to `DateBox` and use your own class in columns.

Comment: Hello H.E..I want this feature, as the user should be able to remove the date and save it back to database, not just changing the date. I will try your workaround though I have tried changing the DatePicker to DateBox, but that doesn't help either.